# Access Tokens for External users in Office 365

Tags: azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0

If one of our SharePoint online Sites has been shared with a external user using his LiveID (Microsoft Account like hotmail).

Does this external user can be authenticated by our Azure AD to be able to call applications using OAuth? Does this user get a valid access token by our Azure AD?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is able for guest users to consent to applications, granting them the same access that members have in your directory.

More detail about guest user management and limitations you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-create-users#guest-user-management-and-limitations).

Comment: How do we can prevent external users to be able to call applications that are secured by Azure AD in that case?

Comment: Did you mean that you protect your application using Azure ad and doesn't want to the external users to login-in? If I understood correctly, the is no such settings we can disable external users to login-in. However, we can enable the **User assignment required to access app** from old portal, then we can assign the users who can access the app based on who are assigned.

Comment: thanks, I think I found out how to prevent external users to run applications that secured by Azure AD. It is about how you configure the application in Azure AD. I think all external users are inside one Azure AD group, so we can just exclude this group from the application configuration.